# Binding an array error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently have a list view in my system which shows a list of html inputs and a create button. I want to create a Customer return item for each row of inputs.Sorry its so complicated. I tried the following and I get the error:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

```
CustomerReturnItem customerreturnitem = new CustomerReturnItem();
customerreturnitem = List1[count];
customerreturnitem.CustomerReturnId = CustomerReturnId;
customerreturnitem.ItemId = PassClass.ItemId[count];"
```

this is my post action:

```
    HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Action4( List<CustomerReturnItem> List1)
            {

                CustomerReturn customerreturn = new CustomerReturn();
                UpdateModel(customerreturn);
                customerreturn.TransactionId = PassClass.TransactionId;
                customerreturn.CustomerId = PassClass.CustomerId;
                customerreturn.DateOfCustomerReturn = System.DateTime.Now;

                db.SaveChanges();
                int CustomerReturnId = customerreturn.CustomerReturnId;
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    for (int count = 0; count < PassClass.ItemCount; count++)
                    {
                        CustomerReturnItem customerreturnitem = new CustomerReturnItem();

                        customerreturnitem = List1[count];
                        customerreturnitem.CustomerReturnId = CustomerReturnId;
                        customerreturnitem.ItemId = PassClass.ItemId[count];
                        UpdateModel(customerreturnitem);
                        db.SaveChanges();


                    }
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Action5");
            }
```

**My View**

```
@model BBTprogram.Models.CustomerReturnItem

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Action4";
}

<h2>Action4</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)



        <table>
        <tr>
        <th>
        Item
        </th>
        <th>
        Quantity Baught
        </th>       

        <th>
         <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerReturnQuantity)
        </div>
        </th>
        <th>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerReasonForReturn)
        </div>
        </th>
        <th>
         <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Resellable)
        </div>
        </th>
         </tr>
         @for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.CountInfo; i++)
         {

        <tr>
        <td>
        <div>
        @ViewBag.ItemInfo[i]
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div>
        @ViewBag.QuantityInfo[i]
        </div>
        </td>

        <td>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerReturnQuantity)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerReturnQuantity)
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerReasonForReturn)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerReasonForReturn)
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Resellable)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Resellable)
        </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
         }
        </table>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>

}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**This is my model:**

```
namespace BBTprogram.Models
{
    public class CustomerReturnItem
    {
        //Primary Key
        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Required]
        public int CustomerReturnItemId { get; set; }
        // Foreign Key
        public int CustomerReturnId { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        //Other
        [DisplayName("Quantity of returned items")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Returned quantity of item is required")]
        [Range(1, 200,
        ErrorMessage = "Returned quantity of item must be between 1 and 200")]
        public int CustomerReturnQuantity { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Reason for returns")]
        public string CustomerReasonForReturn { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Resellable?")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Resellable is required")]
        public bool Resellable { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Comment: Which line to you get the null reference exception on?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your View renders only one `CustomerReturnItem` :

`@model BBTprogram.Models.CustomerReturnItem`

not plural: `List<BBTprogram.Models.CustomerReturnItem>`

By default `Html.BeginForm` sends to `ActionResult` current model. In your case `CustomerReturnItem`. But your ActionResult expects for `List<CustomerReturnItem>`

Try to change it as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action4(CustomerReturnItem model)
            {
//**Your code here

}
```